# Is it possible to declare a generic event in vb.NET?

Tags: vb.net, events, generics, declaration

I have tried to write:

```
Event EventName(Of T)()
```

But Visual Studio tells me that "Type parameters cannot be specified on this declaration."

Is such a declaration possible or will I have to put T as a regular argument?

Comment: How would you expect to raise such an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Event keyword is similar to declaring a field within your class. You wouldn't expect to find:

```
Private i as GenericClass(Of T)
```

inside a class that isn't already generic.

You can declare a *Delegate* with a generic type:

```
Public Delegate Sub Blah(Of T)()
```

But then you'd declare your event to be of a concrete type:

```
Public Event EventName As Blah(Of Int16)
```

Or if your class was generic, you'd then be able to declare the event as generic too:

```
Public Delegate Sub Blah(Of T)()


Public Class Referral(Of U)


    Public Event EventName As Blah(Of U)

End Class
```

Of course, all of these empty argument lists look rather suspect also. We may do better if you can provide more code/more explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I provided an empty argument list because I wanted to ask purely about the syntax. I thought that an `Event` declaration would be similar to `Function`, where you can declare a generic argument even if the class is not generic itself. Thank you for the clarification.